# Is there any efficient way to take value along rows by indices from numpy array or pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to get value by indices from `np.array` or `pd.DataFrame`. Suppose raw value shape is `[x,y]`, my indices is an array which shape is `[x,z]`. I want to take values for each column by indices. It means that each column will changed to `z` columns. I tried to use `take` directly, but it was not my want. Thus, I have to apply the method for columns loop. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]])
print(f"input array:\n{arr}")

indices = np.asarray([[-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 0]]).T
print(f"indices:\n{indices}")

res_0 = arr.take(indices)
print(f"take directly:\n{res_0}")

result_list = []
for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
    result_list.append(arr[:, i].take(indices))

res_1 = np.concatenate(result_list, axis=-1)
print(f"expected result:\n{res_1}")
```

The output of the code is as follows:

```
input array:
[[0 1 2 4]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [2 3 4 5]]
indices:
[[-1 -1]
 [ 0 -1]
 [ 1  0]]
take directly:
[[5 5]
 [0 5]
 [1 0]]
expected result:
[[2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5]
 [0 2 1 3 2 4 4 5]
 [1 0 2 1 3 2 4 4]]
```

For each column of `arr`, using the indices to select will generate two new columns (each column in indices will generate a new column). Thus, we finally get a new array with shape `[3, 4*2]`.

Using take directly can not achieve my target, while using loop is not so neat.

Is there any more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: You included these `print` statements, but didn't show the results?  Why not?

Comment: Could you change `arr` so the choice of columns versus rows isn't ambiguous?

Comment: @hpaulj I have added results and change the shape of arr...